# Backpropagation through 1D convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to backpropagate through 1dconv as it is with conv2d_backprop_input for 2dconv?

I'm trying to apply different methods for relevance propagation on temporal data whereof I apply 1d-convolutions. In order to propagate the relevance in need to backpropagate through 1d-layers. Is this possible?

This is an example of the backpropagation of a 2dconv:

```
def backprop_conv(self, activation, kernel, relevance, strides, padding='SAME'):
    W_p = tf.maximum(0., kernel)
    z = nn_ops.conv2d(activation, W_p, strides, padding) + 1e-10
    s = relevance / z
    c = nn_ops.conv2d_backprop_input(tf.shape(activation), W_p, s, strides, padding)
    return activation * c
```

Comment: Maybe elaborate a little more. Reading your post I didn't even know what you are talking about until I saw the tags.

Comment: Tried adding some explanations